# Bug: Background image looks like gunk on monitor.

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, design

Steps to reproduce:

1. Visit [Programmers - Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [Programmers chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/programmers) in browser.
2. Keep page open for a while.
3. Notice blemish on monitor at edge of vision, reach with hand or cloth to clean it off.
4. Realize that blemish is actually the theme's background image and you just wiped it for nothing/touched monitor with finger and *actually made it worse*. Possible infinite loop condition.

(P.S. I would've tagged this [fun] if I had the rep. =))

Comment: Needz moar coffee stains!

Comment: I was tempted to add a realistic fly there somewhere... I'm glad I didn't then.

Comment: This is Meta, there is no fun, just anger, disappointment and hate.  ;-)

Comment: @Jin fake sneeze spots would be more evil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that's the point. It's supposed to look like the whiteboard drawings that got left on there too long and no longer quite erases. That's my guess anyway.

Comment: Yep, by design surely?  Nicely quirky in my book.

Comment: Yes it's by design, and don't call me Shirley.